# Can we add more fields on stellar?

Tags: transactions

I was wondering how to add more fields on transactions like the memo field.Is it possible to do so.. How can I do that?

Answer (score 6):

If you need to store some information attached to any account you can use `ManageData` operation to store key/value pairs, more here https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/list-of-operations.html#manage-data

Please note that ManageData operation will store information for the account, which can be edited/deleted, and not attached to a particular transaction. Where as Memo field is attached unique to every transaction.

Comment: I don't want this.. Actually I want to add field same as memo field which can used for attaching data at the time of transaction...

Comment: Use the memo field to link to some entry in the manage data, or something like an IPFS hash (https://ipfs.io/).

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a memo field in stellar that you can add in a transaction, check out this link

https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/transactions.html

Comment: Yeah I know that there is a memo field in stellar which can be added during transaction... But I want to add more fields like memo field...